# How to clear redis database when nodejs server disconnect?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io, event-handling

I have a simple chatroom application using a node express server.
This uses a redis database connection to store the nicknames of the joined clients.

I need to clear the redis SET of nicknames named `members` when the server is closed/disconnected.
This can be done as following:

```
redisClient.del("members", function(err, reply){
    console.log("members set delete :" + reply);
});
```

But where should I put this code? How to handle the final event from the server when disconnection, from the server side?

**Server code - chatroom.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redis = require('redis');
var redisClient = redis.createClient();

io.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log("client connected...");
});

io.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('join', function(name){
        client.nickname = name;
        //adding names
        client.broadcast.emit("add member", name);
        redisClient.smembers('members', function(err, names) {
            names.forEach(function(name){   
                client.emit('add member', name);    
            }); 
        });
        client.emit('add member', client.nickname)
        redisClient.sadd("members", name);
    });

    // remove clients on disconnect
    client.on('disconnect', function(name){
        client.broadcast.emit("remove member", client.nickname);
        redisClient.srem("members", client.nickname);   
    });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});
server.listen(8080);
```

**Client code - views/index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Socket.io Client</title>
        <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Chat box</h2><br>
        <h4 id="status"></h4><br>
        <div>
            <h3>Active members</h3>
            <ul id="members"></ul>
        </div>

        <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');

            socket.on('connect', function(data){
                nickname = prompt("What is your nickname?");
                $('#status').html('Connected to Chat Room as \''+nickname+'\'.');        
                socket.emit('join', nickname);
            });

            socket.on('add member', function(name) {
                var member = $('<li>'+name+'</li>').data('name', name);
                $('#members').append(member);   
            });

            socket.on('remove member', function(name) {
                $('#members li').filter(function() { return $.text([this]) === name; }).remove();   
            });

            socket.on('disconnect', function(data){
                $('#status').html('Chatroom Server Down!');        
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

> **How to clear the redis database set when nodejs server disconnect?**

Answer (score 1):

you can use **error** or **end** events on redisclient, check the [Redis Package Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

```
redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
      console.log("Error " + err)
      // delete here
});
```

However, since your connection is closed, it is more healthy to delete on first connection to redis each time. do it on reconnection state too.

Answer (score 1):

When a socket.io connection dies, an event named `disconnect` is fired. Register your reset logic to that callback.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    redisClient.del("members", function(err, reply){
    console.log("members set delete :" + reply);
    });
  });
});
```

Credits : [How can i handle Close event in Socket.io?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077719/how-can-i-handle-close-event-in-socket-io)