# Socket.IO - how can I tell the server which specific client disconnected?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I followed [a different S/O answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077719/how-can-i-handle-close-event-in-socket-io) to figure out how to communicate to my server that a client disconnected by using

```
var socket = io.connect(<your_url>, {
'sync disconnect on unload': true });
```

The problem is, since this is part of the original socket configuration, I can't tell from the server which of my clients actually disconnected. On my client-side, I display a list of usernames for all connected clients, so I need to know which username to remove from that list for the remaining clients.

server-side code that gets triggered when a client closes out is:

```
socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
        console.log('user disconnected', reason);
    });
```

but the "reason" variable turns out to just be a string that says: "transport close" with no information about the actual client that disconnected.

One approach I thought of was, whenever a client disconnects, the server can request a response from all connected clients and use that to send out an updated list every time, but this seems excessive. I'd much prefer to know which client disconnected when they disconnect, and simply broadcast the id of the newly disconnected client, so the other clients are able to update their respective user lists locally. When a new client joins, after all, I broadcast that client's username, so all clients can update locally - I'd like to use the same pattern when a client disconnects.

In short, does anyone know a way to, within the "sync disconnect on unload" configuration of socket.io, also send the client's ID on unload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to keep an array in the server of active participants, adding to it every time they connect.

```
let users = []
socket.on('join', data => {
   data.id === socket.id
   users.push(data)
})

socket.on('disconnect', reason => {
   let user = users.find(u => u.id === socket.id)
   // we emit an event from the server, not from a particular socket
   io.emit('player disconnected', {
      user
   }
})
```